# replace the value of anchor tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html
I need to go through each anchor tag and check if the anchor tag value is APL

```
$('a').text()="APL"
```

If value is equal to APL i need to remove the hyperlink on the Status column.

Is there i can loop through all the anchor tags and remove the hyperlink tag

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Class</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>185</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <DETAIL</td>
          <td><a href="Detail.aspx?id=185" target="_blank">APL</a>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>186</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <DETAIL</td>
          <td><a href="Detail.aspx?id=185" target="_blank">DDL</a>
          </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

1) filter function to get anchor elements having text as APL.

2) And `.removeAttr()` for removing attribute `href`

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim() === "APL" ;
  }).removeAttr("href");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Class</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>185</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <DETAIL</td>
          <td><a href="Detail.aspx?id=185" target="_blank">APL</a>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>186</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <DETAIL</td>
          <td><a href="Detail.aspx?id=185" target="_blank">DDL</a>
          </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('a')` is maybe quite a large selector for such a function, but the following works.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).text() == 'APL' ) {
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v8qr2vgL/